# Diminishing size of nested brackets

Tags: macros, environments, brackets, size

I'm writing in a notation that uses lots of nested brackets, e.g. [[], [[]], [[], []]]

This easily gets difficult to read and is a lot more readable when written like `$\Bigl[ \bigl[ \bigr], \bigl[ [], [] \bigr] \Bigr]$` (ie when inner brackets are smaller).

Is there a way to write a command or environment so that latex does this automatically for me? I hoping to just to be able to type something like `$\nest{[[], [[], []]]}` and then latex renders the brackets nicely with decreasing size (perhaps using custom sizes between \Big and \big and so on)

I'm new to writing custom commands so some basic examples would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  mathtools has some ways to combine these with custom commands.  Do you have some of yours that we could work from?

Comment: @Teepeemm not sure what you mean by 'these'. Other than a python script I've been copying and pasting back and forth, I don't have anything so far.

Comment: What is the nature of your text? e.g., mathematical, simple textual, code-listing. Suggestions might differ according to that.

Comment: @Niranjan mostly mathematical